# Flatten xml column into new columns

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table like this:

```
---id----Id2-----ID3-----
   1      2      <Account ID="123" NR = "234" Type="type1" Ratio = "31">
                  <FIELD>
                     <Name> Peter </Name>
                     <LastName> Johnson </LastName>
                     <Address> Millington </Address>
                     <Nr> 30 </Nr>
                  </FIELD>
                  <FIELD>
                     <Name> Jessica</Name>
                     <LastName> Johnson </LastName>
                     <Address> Millington </Address>
                     <Nr> 30 </Nr>
                  </FIELD>
                 </ACCOUNT>
```

ID3 can have multiple "Field"s within each Account (not fixed size). I want the fields to become columns for each id. Like this:

```
---id--------id2--------Name-----Lastname-----Address-----Nr-----
    1         2         Peter     Johnson     Millington   30
    1         2         Jessica   Johnson     Millington   30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `nodes` together with `cross apply` to break down your xml to row level:

```
declare @tmp table (id int,Id2 int,ID3 xml)
declare @xml XML = '<Account ID="123" NR = "234" Type="type1" Ratio = "31"> <FIELD> <Name> Peter </Name> <LastName> Johnson </LastName> <Address> Millington </Address> <Nr> 30 </Nr> </FIELD> <FIELD> <Name> Jessica</Name> <LastName> Johnson </LastName> <Address> Millington </Address> <Nr> 30 </Nr> </FIELD> </Account>'

insert into @tmp values(1, 2, @xml)

SELECT x.id
      ,x.id2
      ,c.value('Name[1]'    , 'nvarchar(200)') AS [Name]
      ,c.value('LastName[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') AS LastName
      ,c.value('Address[1]' , 'nvarchar(200)') AS [Address]
      ,c.value('Nr[1]'      , 'nvarchar(200)') AS Nr
FROM @tmp x
cross apply x.ID3.nodes('Account/FIELD') T(c)
```

Results:

[image]

*Please note that you have non-matching tags (`<Account></ACCOUNT>`, `<Name></NAME>`). Tags case must be equal in opening and closing tags.*

In your specific case the query should look like this (just replace `[YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE]` with the actual name of your table):

```
SELECT x.id
      ,x.id2
      ,c.value('Name[1]'    , 'nvarchar(200)') AS [Name]
      ,c.value('LastName[1]', 'nvarchar(200)') AS LastName
      ,c.value('Address[1]' , 'nvarchar(200)') AS [Address]
      ,c.value('Nr[1]'      , 'nvarchar(200)') AS Nr
FROM [YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE] x
cross apply x.ID3.nodes('Account/FIELD') T(c)
```

Comment: Yes, this is right: my answer contains just a sample to show you how it works. You should edit my query to apply it directly to your table.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? Based on my example

Comment: @JoeDoe sure: please edit your question adding the DDL for your table (`CREATE TABLE ...`) and I will post an updated answer based on the structure of your table.

Comment: Well I left joined the XML column which is Datatype XML to this table with ID and ID2 which are INT both...I tried to declare an xml XML by only selecting the XML column: declare xml XML = (select ITEM_RESPONSE from #Temp2) but cannot set variable to a whole table.....Make sense....get error: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The tmp table you are creating is my exactly the same as my starting table (in the example above) as I see it....

Comment: @JoeDoe very well, so you just have to remove the `declare` and `insert` statements and replace `@tmp` with the name of your table (see updated answer)

Comment: I have tried that, but the result I get is an empty table with the right columns names.... :/